# Is dereferencing a variable address the same as dereferencing a variable of type pointer that contains that address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Consider this code :

```
int main(){
   
   
   int a = 10;
   int* p = &a;

   //case 1

   *(&a);
   *p;

   //case 2

   *((&a) + 1);
   *( p + 1 );
   
   
}
```

1. Are the two forms the same ?
2. Is it correct to assert that a pointer is just an address that "can" be stored in a variable for later use ?
3. Are there some caveats when not using a pointer variable to dereference an address ?

Comment: #2... Turn it around just a bit: "A pointer is a variable that is used to store a memory address for later use."

Comment: Fe203, " If v is a variable of type T, then &v is a pionter with type T *". This is one of the comments I received when asking this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/76782387/14595895

Comment: Fe203, so it turns out that if I have int a = 10; &a is indeed a pointer. This means that even they say a pointer is a variable that contains an address in the larger sense the address of an object is a pointer that refers to a certain type

Comment: The value of a variable (a "pointer") can be changed (re-assigned). The "address of" a variable cannot... You're free to think what you want...

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Yes, `*p` and `*(&a)` are the exact same. The variable `p` simply contains the memory address of `a`.

2.
A pointer is simply a variable that contains a number that is interpreted as a memory address, most often a `uint32_t` for 32 bit systems and a `uint64_t` for 64 bit ones.

3.
To my knowledge there aren't any. Both are just the same memory address.

Comment: Nicholas, but why do people keep saying that a pointer is a variable ? Should it be more correct to say that a pointer is just an address that refers to a certain type and that "can be stored" in a special kind of variable that holds a pointer. ?

Comment: You can change the value in a pointer, `p++`, therefore it is a variable.

Comment: Also, "pointer arithmetic" changes the value of the variable (that is a pointer) by the appropriate number of bytes for the datatype that is being pointed at.

Comment: @alessiosolari A pointer is a variable, and in that variable is a memory address. When we dereference the pointer the compiler looks at that memory address and gives us the value found there. The type of the pointer just tells the compiler how to interpret the binary data at the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1:

`*(&a);` de-references the address of `a` resulting in the value stored in `a`.

`*p;` de-references the value stored in `p` which is the address of `a` also resulting in the value stored in `a`.

So both have the same effect.

similarly, in case 2:

```
*((&a) + 1);
*( p + 1 );
```

both statements have the same effect but be careful here, `a` is declared as a variable of type `int`, not an array. As such, both statements have semantic error and result in undefined behavior.

Comment: machine_1, but why do people keep saying that a pointer is a variable ? Should it be more correct to say that a pointer is just an address that refers to a certain type and that "can be stored" in a special kind of variable that holds a pointer ?

Comment: I mean the pointer in and of itself is just an address of a certain type...

Comment: A pointer is a special kind of variable that stores the address of another object.

Comment: machine_1, I've heard a lot of people saying that a pointer is just an address. If as you say it is a variable then why do we get the same result when dereferencing a raw address ?

Comment: @alessiosolari - `p` is a "variable", because its value can vary. If you do `p = &b;`, for example, it is no longer "just the address of a".

Comment: BoP, if &a is not a pointer then why if we do "pointer" arithmetic we get the same result as if we were to use a pointer variable. For example I can do (&a) + 1 and p +1 and I get the same result. The fact that I'm doing "pointer" arithmetic does imply that &a must be a pointer otherwise it would have been called "address arithmetic". Moreover it isn't just a variable pointer that has information about the type of object if points to, the &a address in and of itself has information about the type of object it points to because if we dereference *(&a) we get an int.

Comment: BoP, I've also asked this kind of  questions on a previous post :  stackoverflow.com/q/76782387/14595895 and it seems like there are opposite point of views as far as this matter is concerned. So what is the truth ?

Comment: From the IBM documentation "The & (address) operator yields a pointer to its operand. The operand must be an lvalue, a function designator, or a qualified name. It cannot be a bit field, nor can it have the storage class register."